# Can I run a customized Circle CI build script using the 'nightly build' feature?

Tags: circleci

I'm trying to set up a scheduled job that runs 10 Circle CI builds overnight for feature-test-failure purposes.

I found the Circle CI nightly build documentation and I was able to implement it, but each build is a full build (running all `pre` and `post` test processes).  I just want to run one suite of tests (we are running multiple in our normal builds).

I know I could accomplish this with an `if` statement inside of the `circle.yml` file.

I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so technically not an `if` statement... We ended up doing this.  It's not the greatest but it cuts it down to one line (plus the comment).  We are on Heroku, so we used Heroku Scheduler to run the bash script (that passes the `RUN_NIGHTLY_BUILD` parameter that to Circle CI and kick off the build (via `POST`).

`./circle.yml`:

```
override:
   # will run if not nightly build
   - test -n "${RUN_NIGHTLY_BUILD}" || bundle exec rake spec:units
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently an `if` condition is the only thing we can offer in this case. Sorry about that :(